# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios4, nsmutablearray

If I have an NSMutableArray with 10 objects

I run this line of code

```
[tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

then

`[tempArray count]` should return 9

but does the entire Array shift up

Object At Index 1 moves to Index 0
Object at Index 2 moves to Index 1
...
Object at Index 9 moves to Index 8

or is Index 0 = nil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [NSMutableArray documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index.

Comment: right but is this done by iOS or do we have to manually make a method to do this? (Sorry for the dumb question).

Answer (score 2):

The array will shift all of the objects down 1 from the right of the removed index. Index 0 will be what was at index 1 and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

`removeObjectAtIndex` **shifts indexes down**

`insertObjectAtIndex` **shifts indexed up**

`addObject` adds object at the end so there is no shifting